# How often has weather interfered with the Deep Space Network?

Tags: deep-space-network, weather

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26389/26446) provides some information about the potential that precipitation can interfere with signals of the [Deep Space Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Space_Network).  **In practice, how often** (a count, ratio or percent) **has weather interfered with intended contacts of the DSN?**

(Looking for actual numbers, not commentary that Goldstone is in a desert.)

Comment: commentary instead that it rains in Spain, and not only on the plain (and also in Australia though it doesn't rhyme) See [slide #5](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20140012572.pdf) form [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26389/12102) The challenge to answering is that high water vapor can block some DSN activities (e.g. VLBI or delta-differential doppler ranging) or some bands (X-band and experimental ones) without interfering with others.  Strong wind might affect highest bands also. It's not going to be a simple number based on a boolean like rainouts in baseball.

Comment: Hurricane winds. For example for Soviet P-400 radiotelescope: "Guidance drives are designed to operate at wind speeds up to 25 m/s".