# Deep Space Network's transmitter power versus frequency?

Tags: deep-space-network

Just a general question: In regards to the Deep Space Network antennas, how does power from the transmitter of the antenna relate to the frequency used? I believe the antennas use X band frequency for uplink and downlink to communicate with the Voyager spacecrafts, but is there a limit of the power needed to reach that frequency?

Comment: Interesting question! [One of them has 400 kW on S-band](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18956/12102) but this is a special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking for technical information about spacecraft communications and other tech stuff, think DESCANSO. What is that? I'm glad you asked!  [When was the idea behind the DESCANSO Book Series first conceived, by whom, and what is it's “mission”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22968/12102)

In [Volume 13, Deep Space Communications, Jim Taylor, Editor](https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/monograph/series13/DeepCommoOverall--141030A_ama.pdf) in Table 2.2 on page 34, you can see that the transmit power *available* for both the 34 meter dishes (BWG = "[beam waveguide antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_waveguide_antenna)") and the 70 meter dishes and for both S-band and X-band **are all 20 kW.**

However, the EIRP (Effective Isotropic Radiated Power) is different in each case because the gain of the antenna varies with the ratio of the diameter to the wavelength squared. So 70 m will have about +6.3 dB over 34 meters, and X-band will have +10.6 dB over S-band.

---

The 400 kW for the 70 meter dish at Goldstone is an exception that is rarely if ever used [Has DSS-43 ever been used in high power mode (>>20 kW) for an emergency situation](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18956/12102) and the Ka-band is not used for deep space, though it is used in some cases...

- [What is the highest non-optical frequency used or tested for use in deep space communication?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23335/12102)
- [Will there be “Near Space” Ka-band allocations for TESS?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21770/12102)

---

> [image: DESCANSO vol 13 Table 2.2]